# addEventListener not working with onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome, addeventlistener, onbeforeunload

```
window.addEventListener("onbeforeunload",function() {return "are you sure?"});
```

^ This does not seem to work... at all... the page will simply close without displaying the confirmation box...

I realize that...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "are you sure?"}
```

Will work, but I want to add to the functionality (e.g. add many event listeners to the "onbeforeunload" function) not rewrite the function completely!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Remove the `on` from `onbeforeunload`.

Also, be aware that `addEventListener` will not work in the older IE's and possibly other browsers. If you want consistent event binding use a library.

Comment: Here is the cross-browser solution for addEvent : `function addEvent(evt,fn,useCapture){if(this.addEventListener){this.addEventListener(evt,fn,useCapture);return true;}else if(this.attachEvent){var r=this.attachEvent('on'+evt,fn);return r;}else this['on'+evt]=fn;}Object.prototype.addEvent=addEvent;` (write the function like this : object.addEvent(event,function,useCapture); ).

Comment: that seems to be not working in the latest FF - 14.0.1 anymore

Comment: @Marcin It's no longer enough to just return a string. You must set `event.returnValue` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload))

Comment: Why is this no longer working? Did browsers change? I'm using this: `window.addEventListener("beforeunload",() => {return 'Stop')};`

Answer (score 28):

There is an "almost cross-browser working example" at Mozila Developer Network [API reference for beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload). Use their code.

## in 2014, that was

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;     //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                                //Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
});
```

## in 2020, it now is

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  event.returnValue = '';
});
```

## all of the above?

If I ever needed this, I'd want to entrust the job to a library. If I had to do this myself, I imagine one can do all of the above, just to be extra sure

- do not try to set meaningful message text, it will only give inconsistent UX
- `event = event || window.event`
- `event.preventDefault()`, maybe after check that preventDefault is defined?
- `event.returnValue = ''`
- `return ''`

Comment: no matter which way I do it I can't customize the message

Comment: @toddmo Nowadays, the browsers don't show the custom message. That's a security/UX feature. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480. Or the linked MDN page there. This is something that came up after the answer was written.

Comment: Thanks I finally saw that too :)

Comment: And it seems nowadays you shouldn't put a return statement, just put `e.returnValue = whatever;`.

Comment: @ivkremer nope. nowadays, you don't get custom message, as toddmo found out. in the old days, you'd set `e.returnValue` for some browsers, and `return` the message string for other browsers. (well, you'd do both, but only one would produce the effect, depending which browser is used, while the other would be ignored)

Comment: @user7610 It's really strange, I'm confused a bit. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ivkremer/reg9q739/. If you comment the mentioned line, you won't get a prompt window.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. If I debug the code, it works, but if I don't debug, it doesn't and just exists

Comment: `event.returnValue` is a boolean, not a string. To be safe on all major browsers, you need to do: `event.preventDefault(); event.returnValue = true; return someMessage`. The message won't show up, but it's probably safe to do so, just in case there's some weird browser that decides to display it.

Comment: Can't thank you enough.

Comment: For those wanting a conditional confirmation, setting `event.returnValue` to anything is enough to show the confirmation box. Even setting it to null, false, or undefined causes the box to show (test on Chrome v111).

Answer (score 2):

There's no prefix `on` for the *EventListeners* but it's applicable or may I say necessary for *EventHandlers*

So, just keep in mind that

> EventHandlers = **prefix on**
>
> EventListeners = **prefix off**